# More elegant way of aligning several divs in a navbar?

Tags: html, css

i just started playing around with HTML and CSS a few weeks ago and would appreciate some help. I am looking for an elegant way to align several elements in a header.

I am unfamiliar with using grids. I tried using display: inline-block and display: table but i didnt get it to work the way Id like to. So I had to use floats, which works, but i feel like its forced.

Id also like to have the content appear in the same range as .nav-content, but I guess 55% of the container will be different than 55% of the header?

Anyways, heres the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/******************************************
Header / Navbar
*******************************************/

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
  position: fixed;
  Z-Index: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.6;
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.nav-content {
  width: 55%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-logo,
.navigation li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-right,
.nav-btn {
  float: right;
}
.nav-left {
  font-size: 26;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
}
.nav-left li {
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
.navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav-right {
  padding-right: 1%;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="We are medium. We write about startups.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Medium, blogging, startups, entrepreneurship, Unternehmer, Gründung, Unternehmensgründung, gründen, Venture Capital, Business Angel, Investor, Wagniskapital, Risikokapital">
  <meta name="author" content="William Middendorf">
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Medium</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,400italic|Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navigation">
      <!--Navigation-->
      <div class="nav-left">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-logo">Blogger</div>
        <div class="nav-btn">
          <button class="wrt-btn">Schreib' einen Artikel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-right">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" style="cursor: auto;">Log In</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" style="cursor: auto;">Register</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of Navigation / Header-->

  </div>
  <!--End of Container-->
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have a jsBin to show?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with floats, and "more elegant" is pretty subjective. If the CSS works, it works.

Comment: @ChrisBaker using floats to layout is not elegant. When you need to put tons of "clearfix", something wrong are making. Floats are for floating elements, not for layouts. Displays, flexbox, positioning, etc, there are more ways to make layouts than floats. Floats are neccesary when we need to compatibilize years ago to IE7 and less. Now NOT

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Floats are a tool in CSS, there's no reason to carry on a cargo cult against them. They are neither elegant nor inelegant, simply another tool. If it works and is within the standard, it works. "Elegant" is subjective, I did not say floats are elegant. Do I advocate building your entire layout with floats? No. Do I think you're a bad human being if you use float a few times and your page looks good? No. Does any non-technical consumer of web content care either way? Critically important: **no**.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I work repairing a lot of css that since the first line to the last line all are floats (a block, a line, an image, etc). And each 2 lines of html, then will be a clearfix. That's elegant? NO. That's subjective? NO. It's true. Clearfixes are FIXES, and when you develop with a lot of fixes, something wrong are making

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Clearing floats isn't "fixing" something broken, that's just the trendy name the practice took on. Floats are intended to remain open until closed, it's the way the feature works. Anyway, these days most people just use `:after` for clearing, rather than actual elements in the markup with a `clearfix` class. That said... it's old school, but it isn't evil, it's just how it was done. Don't write new code like that, I agree with you there! Just like we don't use tables for layout anymore, that doesn't mean we never use tables ever again for anything.

Comment: p.s. check out StackOverflow's layout markup on the answers below :p

Comment: I said: "floats are for floating elements", so I use floats. But not to make layouts. i use it for the purpose that it is. I enjoy this discussion but I think that's finished xD. See you soon!

Comment: And the layout is with tables.... hahahaha, I was seeing long time ago the tables of the comments, but not the answers. Good appointment

Answer (score 2):

Float is bad way to go here. You will not be able to center them later in mobile view, if needed.

Use `display: inline-block;` and don't leave spaces or new lines is html code between the buttons, to avoid gap between them.

Comment: "will not be able to center them" -- a media query with `float:none` would be effective. There's nothing wrong with floats, especially when you want floated content. Your note about spaces in the markup is, in my view, a clue that the approach isn't the best one.

Comment: When using display: inline-block, do i just add margins in order to place them whereever i want? Is this responsive? Or do i give a percentage width? And if so, how to i place elements on the right or left side of that width? :confused

Comment: @WilliamJohn - adding margin or defining a width depends on what you need to accomplish. Align elements by defining the text-align on their parent.

Comment: @ChrisBaker defining a float and then disabling it in media query is not good practise. With inline-block you don't need to do that, just change the text-align of the parent. Aside that floating elements are not taking height if you dont use clear fix. And try to change float from "left" to "right" and you will see that all elements are ging to reverse their order. As for the spaces, it looks bad for humans in code, not for robots. And even in that case you can comment the newlines in markup. But the result is clearer and consistent.

Comment: Modifying floats with media queries is perfectly acceptable practice, just like any other CSS attribute -- there is absolutely no technical evidence for your assertion. Use the standard tools that work best for your use case. If floats make sense, there's no reason to avoid them. If they don't make sense, don't use them. If you're going to move the element around for mobile, maybe floating isn't the best tool. Or, maybe floats can stay floating for mobile. It seems to me that you're throwing around "bad practice" without any justification. Anyway.

Comment: Yes it is bad practice to define things and than disable them in media queries when you have perfect alternative, like you do in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

using `inline-block` and width percentages and `text-align`, you can avoid using floats and margins. here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/349/

```
.section, li, .nav-logo, .nav-btn {
    display:inline-block;
}
.nav-left, .nav-right, .nav-content {
    width: 32%;
}
.nav-right {
    text-align: right;
}
.nav-logo, .nav-btn {
    width: 49%;
}
```

Comment: thank you! should i split up the .nav-content section? i wanted to achieve the same width of that section with the following main content area, while aligned the button right and the logo left so that the website is nice and fluid.

Comment: you can just adjust the widths of `.nav-left`, `.nav-right` and `.nav-content` to accommodate the width of the content like this: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/350/